# Why I can't get objects from file properly?

Tags: java, serialization

I have list of custom objects that I writre and then read to file.

Here is my class:

```
public class Book implements Serializable{
   private int isbn;
   private String category;
   private String authorName;

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getCatId() {
        return category;
    }


    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public Book() {}

    //copy book 
    public Book(Book book, int id) {
        this.category = book.category;
        this.title = book.title;
        this.authorName = book.authorName;
        this.isbn = id;
    } 
}
```

Here is function that I use to write the list of objects:

```
private static <T> void writeToFile(List<T> items, String fileName) {
    try {
        String path = "src\\hw1\\library\\repos\\" + fileName;

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(path, true);// true- means append to file
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

        // Write objects to file
        o.writeObject(items);
        o.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

And here  is function that I reade from the list:

```
private static <T> List<T> readFromFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
         String path = "src\\hw1\\library\\repos\\" +fileName ;

         FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(path);
         ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
         // Read objects
         List<T> items = (List<T>)oi.readObject();
         oi.close();
         fi.close();

         return items;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

The List of objects is written to the file, 
but when I try to read it with function above the objects that I get from file only objects that was written to file first time.

Any idea why I get from file only objects that was written to file first time?

Comment: so before I write to file I need to read it and then write again with new and old objects?

Answer (score 0):

I only asume that

> but when I try to read it with function above the objects that I get
>   from file only objects that was written to file first time.

Single write will put given list into a file, second write will *put another list* into that file - because you are *appending to file*

Now, you read method **always reads from the begining** so every invocation of `readFromFile` will result in reading the same (very first) object (list in your case) from given file. You would have to do do more `f.readObject()` on the same stream.

If you are not going to read all objects at once, I would suggest to use 1 file per list, so you will not have use file seeking to "shift" position of file pointer (nor doing empty `f.readObject()` invocations)